# dualboot installation ubuntu with window 10

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

I have two questions:

1. I just got a brand new HP Envy Phoenix 850qe desktop with Windows 10 pre-installed. I created a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 LTS DVD, which works just fine on my win 7 Dell desktop. However, this DVD does not seem to work on my new Windows 10 PC. The DVD is being accesedbut nothing happens.
2. Will there be any drivers missing to support my NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 745 4GB DDR3 FH GFX?

I am about to call HP support to replace Windows 10 with Windows 7, but I thought I'd ask around first.

Comment: You might consider the difference between bios and uefi ... the new HP probably has uefi with might be preventing the DVD from booting.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling **UEFI Secure Boot** andd changing the **boot order**. If this dosen't help, then your best bet is to get a copy of VMware Workstation(for Windows), An Ubuntu ISO File and create a virtual machine,give the VM most of your system storage and specification and use the VM like it is your **real** machine. I know it's probably not the best solution, but it's not like you're pushing yourself to force Ubuntu on to your computer